# Renaming files based on matching IDs taken from CSV

Tags: powershell

I have the following `csv` list (in reality 1000s of lines):

```
needle,code
123456,AB
121212,BB
33333333,CVV
```

And I have a directory containing pdf files (again, 1000s in reality):

```
dsadsadsa.343222.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.123456.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.111111.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.33333333.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
dsadsadsa.33333333.fsdgdsfdsfdsf.dsad.pdf
```

For each needle in the csv:

- I have to see if there is a pdf containing that needle (there might be 0 or more matches)
- If there is a match, I have to prepend the respective code to the name

For the example, I have a match for `123456` and 2 for `33333333`, so I have to rename into:

```
AB.dsadsadsa.123456.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
CVV.dsadsadsa.33333333.dsads23213jkjl.saddsa.pdf
CVV.dsadsadsa.33333333.fsdgdsfdsfdsf.dsad.pdf
```

As I am quite new to Powershell, I started with iterating through the files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "R:\files" | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "$needle" } | %{ Rename-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -NewName ({0}_{1} -f $code,$_.Name) }
```

Obviously this does not work because I am not populating `$needle` and `$code`.

Can you please help me:

- reading through the `csv` line by line, populating `$needle` and `$code`
- and rename the file accordingly?

Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

From your example filenames, the needle code is always after the first dot and followed by another dot. If you can rely on that, then you can build a hashtable mapping needle -> code + dot, snip that bit out of each filename and look for it in the hashtable.

If the needle code doesn't match anything in the hashtable it will return $null, and the NewName will be the same as the current name; a quick test says that in that case, Rename-Item doesn't do anything.

```
$pairs = @{}
Import-CSV .\data.csv | ForEach-Object { $pairs[$_.needle] = $_.code+"." }

Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName { $pairs[$_.Name.Split('.')[1]] + $_.Name } -WhatIf
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm also trying to log the changes that are made: `Get-ChildItem "C:\files" | { $($Hash[$_.Name.Split('.')[1]] + $_.Name) >> "C:\output.txt" }` but this doesn't work. How do I write a logfile with `needle,code,oldfilename,newfilename`?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, or at least get you started.

```
$entries = Import-csv .\file.csv


ForEach ($entry in $entries){
    $filesToRename = Get-ChildItem c:\pathToYourFiles | Where Name -like "*$($entry.needle)*"     

    ForEach ($file in $filesToRename ){

        Rename-Item -Path $file.FullName -NewName "$($entry.code)$($file.BaseName)" -WhatIf

    }

}
```

First, we import your CSV and call it `$entries`.

Then we step through each `$entry` and pull a list of all the files in this directory.  I wanted to do this everytime, in case a file name changes while this is running.  We filter this list of files to only include ones who match the value for needle.  (Also I love the cute property names, of needle and haystack).  We call those matching files `$filesToRename`.

Next, we step through each matching `$file` and run `Rename-Item` on it, giving the full file name and specifying your desired `-NewName`.

I put this in `-WhatIf` mode so that you could safely see what would happen before running it.

If you're happy, remove `-WhatIf` and go with God.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would try to avoid having to pull the directory listing millions of times by nesting `ForEach` loops within eachother. What I would do is create a hashtable out of your first CSV, and then a RegEx pattern out of the needles. Then get the directory listing, run each file through the RegEx match, and rename the file based on the matching string's entry in the hashtable.

```
$Needles = Import-CSV C:\Path\To\File.csv
[regex]$RegExPattern = '^.*(' + (($Needles.needle|%{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|') + ').*$'

$Hash = @{}
$Needles|%{$Hash.Add($_.Needle,$_.code)}



ForEach($File in (Get-ChildItem R:\files)){
    $RegExPattern.Matches($File.Name)|Rename-Item -path $File.FullName -NewName { $Hash["$($_[0].Groups[1])"]+'.'+$File.Name }
}
```